# How order1.addItem(Noodles()) line from main considers that Noodle() instance is same as Item() instance. For me Noddle & Item instance are diff

Tags: kotlin

Kotlin, In this I have a parent class called Item and two sub classes derived from it are Noodles & Vegetable.
Then i have created an Order class which has addItem method which accepts Item of type ITEM.
Then i have a main function.

In main function i am trying to add an item by passing Noodle instance. Code is running fine but i am not able to understand that function is suppose to accept parameter of type Item but it is working fine with Noodle instance, how. Both instance are different then how's is this code working !

```
open class Item(val name: String, val price: Int)

class Noodles : Item("Noodles", 10){
    override fun toString(): String{
        return name
    }
}

class Vegetables(vararg val topping: String) : Item("Vegetables", 5) {
    override fun toString(): String{
        if (topping.isEmpty()){
            return "$name Chef's Choice"
        } else {
            return name + " " + topping.joinToString()

        }
    }
}

class Order(val orderNumber: Int){
    private val itemList = mutableListOf<Item>()
    
    fun addItem(newItem: Item){
        itemList.add(newItem)
    }
    fun addAll(newItems: List<Item>){
        itemList.addAll(newItems)
    }
    fun print(){
        println("Order #${orderNumber}")
        var total = 0
        for(item in itemList){
            println("${item}: $${item.price}")
             total += item.price
        }
        println("Total: $${total}")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val order1 = Order(1) 
    order1.addItem(Noodles())
    order1.print()
    
    println()

    val order2 = Order(2)
    order2.addItem(Noodles())
    order2.addItem(Vegetables())
    order2.print()

    println()
    
    val order3 = Order(3)
    val items = listOf(Noodles(), Vegetables("Carrots", "Beans", "Celery"))
    order3.addAll(items)
    order3.print()
    
}
```

Comment: The fact that Noodle is a subclass of Item is exactly why you are able to pass an instance of Noodle into something that expects an Item.

Comment: This is called *polymorphism*, you can treat a `Noodles` as a `Noodles` or an `Item` because it `is` both of those things. In this case, you're treating it as an `Item` when it's passed into `Order`, and none of that code knows or cares if it's a `Noodles` or some other kind of `Item`. If there were a special `chomp()` method on `Noodles`, you wouldn't be able to call that on an `Item` - first you'd have to check if that `Item` also `is` a `Noodles`